# Python cut words in list after certain length

Tags: character, limit, words

I have a List of entries in the csv file records. I want to limit the length of the elements to 50 characters and save it into the list. My approach does not work.

```
def readfile():
    records = []
    with open(fpath, 'r') as csvfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|')
        for row in csvreader:
            if len(row) == 0:
                continue
            records.append([row[1]] + [x.strip() for x in row[3]])
    return records

def cut_words(records):
    for lines in records:
        for word in lines:
            word = word[0:50]
    return records
```

it does not seem to be saved in the list.... thanks

Comment: You need to save the file. Could you add the part of the code where you read the csv file?

Comment: I thought I save the first 50 characters of each word by "word = word[0:50]" on the position of word in the list

Comment: What is it doing now? Where are you calling the cut_words function?

Comment: Why do you believe that assigning back to the name used as the iterator affects the iterable?

Comment: @MartinGottweis I am calling "records = cut_words(records)" in the main function but when degugging the cut_words function it seems not to save the new "word".

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams for me it seems like you say - he doesn't write in the iterable- Do you know how I can make it running correctely? Thx

Comment: Create a new sequence instead.

Comment: I don't understand.. what is a new sequence?